# How to pass result of api to another api in Controller Java Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two api in AssetController.java

1.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/getString", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
GetResult<String> getString() {
    String str= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return new GetResult<>(str);
}
```

2.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/asset", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveAsset(@Valid @RequestBody AssetDTO asset, BindingResult result)
        throws ValidationException, ServiceException, AccessDeniedException, NotFoundException {....//to do something}
```

I want to use str of api/getString to use in api/asset?How can i do that?
Thanks so much.

Comment: I solved this similar case, but on client side. I used javascript to use first ajax call response to trigger a second ajax call to another controller, within the same process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC, calling another controller from Inside a controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848386/spring-mvc-calling-another-controller-from-inside-a-controller)

Comment: @CristianMeneses This case on server.Thank you.